# How to alter default saving folder in PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How can I alter the default folder for saving new shapes/processing results not as temporary files but copies them to a specific directory let's say my current project directory?

I have tried the respective post-execution script for hooks given in the qgis documentation which is this one:

[image]

I activated the script in the Processing options as [described here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/processing/hooks.html):

But finally it did not work. Any ideas how I can achieve my objective?